# How to create a VAO in openGL ES 3 android

Tags: java, android, opengl-es, opengl-es-3.0

So in normal openGL you can create a VAO like this

```
glGenVetrexArray();
```

and expect this function to create a VAO for you and gives you an int which is VAO ID.

**The problem**

In android the function is like this:

```
glGenVetrexArray(int n , int[] array, int offset);
```

I dont know what are these parameters and I don't know how to create a VAO and get an id using this above method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

n - number(amount) of VAOs to be returned;

array - an array of n-elements with identifiers of created objects;

offset - set offset for VAO (usually = 0).

When creating the VAO, it is made current using the function: GLES30.glBindVertexArray(VAO[0]). After binding the VAO, all calls, such as: glBindBuffer, glEnableVertexAttribArray, glVertexAttribPointer, will affect the current VAO.

```
public class Renderer implements GLSurfaceView.Renderer {
    private int[] VBOIds = new int[2]; // VertexBufferObject Ids
    private int[] VAOId = new int[1]; // VertexArrayObject Id

    public Renderer(...) {
        // create vertex buffer objects
        VBOIds[0] = 0;
        VBOIds[1] = 0;
        GLES30.glGenBuffers(2, VBO, 0);
        ...
        GLES30.glBindBuffer(GLES30.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO[0]);
        GLES30.glBufferData(GLES30.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, verticesData.length * 4,
                    vertices, GLES30.GL_STATIC_DRAW);
        ...
        GLES30.glBindBuffer(GLES30.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO[1]);
        GLES30.glBufferData(GLES30.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indicesData.length * 2, indices, GLES30.GL_STATIC_DRAW);
        ...
    }

    public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 glUnused, EGLConfig config) {
        GLES30.glGenVertexArrays(1, VAOId, 0); // Generate VAO Id
        GLES30.glBindVertexArray(VAOId[0]); // Bind the VAO
        // invokes commands glBindBuffer, glEnableVertexAttribArray, 
        // glVertexAttribPointer for VBOs
        ...
        // Reset to the default VAO (default VAO always is 0)
        GLES30.glBindVertexArray(0);
    }

    public void onDrawFrame() {
        ...
        GLES30.glBindVertexArray(VAOId[0]); // active VAO
        // Draw on base the VAO settings
        GLES30.glDrawElements(GLES30.GL_TRIANGLES, indicesData.length,
                      GLES30.GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);
        // Return to the default VAO
        GLES30.glBindVertexArray(0);
    }
}
```

You can see a good example of using VAO [here](https://github.com/danginsburg/opengles3-book/blob/master/Android_Java/Chapter_6/VertexArrayObjects/src/com/openglesbook/VertexArrayObjects/VAORenderer.java)

[Project VertexArrayObjects for Android](https://github.com/danginsburg/opengles3-book/tree/master/Android_Java/Chapter_6/VertexArrayObjects)

Comment: Do you mean like the array of int is a set of VAO IDS that I have to create? And do I pass the array empty or I have to populate with something?

Comment: @SomeUser I think usually one VAO is enough, so you can use an array with one element (new int[1]). Complemented the answer with an example.

Comment: I have one question, I am trying to render a rect using VAO and VBO but the rect doesn't render, note that I didnt implement shaders (could this be the problem), because in normal openGL it is possible to render shape without specifying shader? Thanks for your help.

Comment: @SomeUser Think you should use VAO only in conjunction with shaders. VAO is supported starting from openGL ES 3.0, and the use of shaders in this version is necessarely, as I know. I suggest you compile the project using the link in the answer. He draws a triangle. Then substitute your rectangle vertex data.